# Toggle regex options inside a named capture

Tags: ruby, regex

In a regular expression in Ruby you can name a capture using the syntax:

```
/(?<name>…)/
```

and you can toggle the m/i/x options on/off within a non-capturing group using the syntax:

```
/(?i:[a-z])/
```

Is there any way to combine the two in a single group?

---

All of these work, but I am wondering if there is a simpler option:

```
/(?i:(?<name>…))/      # case-insensitive just within the region
/(?<name>(?i:…))/      # case-insensitive just within the region
/(?i)(?<name>…)(?-i)/  # case-insensitive turned on, then turned off
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do that too:

```
/(?<name>(?i)...)/
```

AFIK, that's all!

Comment: I had thought this would leave the case-insensitive option active, but I was wrong. Nice, and simpler. `"AaAbB"[ /(?<a>(?i)a*)(?<b>b*)/ ] #=> "AaAb"`